# What to do with a hibernating Queen Wasp/Bee

Tags: bugs, bees, wasps

I'm not sure if this is the correct stack exchange or not - please redirect me if you feel another would be more appropriate.

I was swapping out the wreath on my door this evening for a Christmas one and a huge wasp fell out onto the floor. She was so big and sleepy/lethargic that I'm guessing she's a Queen that's hibernating.

I put her outside in a shrub with some cover, but I'm now feeling I probably should have given her a bit more cover or done something more specific.

My question is does anyone know what to do in this situation? How to best help them continue hibernating and survive the winter?

Any advice?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, ask on [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).